# PHP scripting with css

Tags: php, css, web, accessibility

So I am trying to use a php script to generate a cookie that will set the value of the style sheet and apply the style features when a link is pressed I currently have this php script

```
<?php

<link rel="stylesheet" href="alternate.css" type="text/css">
$cookie_name = "styelsheet";
$cookie_value = "styelsheet2.css";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
// 86400 = 1 day
?>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    $stylesheet = "alternate.css";
} else {
    $stylesheet =  $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]
}
?>
```

In which alternate. css is my style sheet. Then I have a hyperlink on the homepage that links to this php file and Im hope that when you press the link it will run the php script (since its linked to it) and then the php script will change the color of the webpage to the value in the cookie?  But currently when I press the link it just asks if I want to open or download the php script not the outcome I wanted 
I am trying to implement a scenario like the following 
http://www.bbc.co.uk/accessibility/#  (on the top right corner the layout changes according to what button you press)? Ive tried endlessly to achieve this scenario for my webpage with no luck

Comment: Why do you have the `<link rel="stylesheet" ..>` inside  `<?php ?>` tags?

Comment: To reference the style sheet?

Comment: You don't do that inside of php tags, this should be inside the `<head>` of your document.

Comment: your css link in php will actually break the script in its current format, you need to echo it. But in any case you shouldnt need to do that just declare it in the head tag php doesnt need to know about it unless its actually doing something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Now that i have commented to point to a script breaker here is my answer to your question.

This is not a php concern. PHP is server side, If you want a colour switcher look up javascript colour changer, or jquery theme changer or whatever you want. Your matter is client/browser side not server.